# Android vs iPhone color rendering

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, objective-c

I have used the same color code (#FF0000), but it seems, when compared side by side, Android is showing a slight variance to the red color used.

Is this because of the difference is hardware ?

How can I achieve the same colour standard on both of the devices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never be able to display the exact same colour on all devices.

1. The screen might display colours in a different way (oled, TFT, IPS).
2. The Colourprofile may differ per devices and thus affect the way the colour is shown.

Especially with Android device the colour will look different from device to device. On iOS it might look a bit different between retina and non-retina.

Comment: Yes, Once you fixed it for your Android device it will look different on an other Android device.